Connect Azure Analysis Services to Microsoft Fabric through SQL endpoint
I am trying to connect an Azure Analysis Services model to Microsoft Fabric through a SQL endpoint. When using my own account me@company.com I am able to get data. To schedule the processing of the model every night so I need some kind of authentication to the sql endpoint data source.
Analysis Services support these authentication options (through the gui):

Windows authentication - not supported in Fabric.
Database/sql authentication - not supported in Fabric (unable to create a sql user in Fabric)
Microsoft account(OAuth2) - Can get data through this way but the data source gets tokens that expire after 30 minutes. So this does not work for scheduling.

I need to process the data every night and none of these options work. So I am trying to use a service principal and maybe put it in the connections string but no luck so far. The service principal has access I confirmed this with management studio.
I also tried if the are any options in Tabular Editor 2.19 but no luck so far.
Any solution that makes the model process without a filling in a password every day or doing a deployment every day would be nice.
Added:
The connection from Analysis Services to the Fabric SQL endpoint after deployment to the server will only succeed while going through a gateway. Before that, in visual studio on the laptop, the connection works without a gateway.
Without a gateway the server response when processes is: 'On-Premise Gateway is required to access the data source. Please install a unified gateway for the server [servername]or disable AlwaysUseGateway setting if it's enabled.'

Does this answer your question? Azure analysis service connection using Service principal not working

My question is about authentication to the datasource. That question I believe is authentication to the model.

Just follow the instructions for OAuth as if for Azure SQL Database here:

For tabular models at the 1400 and higher compatibility level using in-memory mode, Azure SQL Database, Azure Synapse, Dynamics 365, and SharePoint List support OAuth credentials. To generate valid tokens, set credentials by using Power Query. Azure Analysis Services manages token refresh for OAuth data sources to avoid timeouts for long-running refresh operations.

Data sources supported in Azure Analysis Services - OAuth Credentials

Hi David thank you for your help, the connection is obliged to go through a gateway to fabric. In your proposed answer there is a note it does not work with a gateway. Could it be that it does not work to connect with Power Query by default? Am I right that the point of the answer you are submitting is that it should be a Power Query login with a regular Office 365 account?

Why would it have to go through a gateway to Fabric?  You don't have public endpoints for Fabric disabled, do you?

It is not disabled. It will not work without the gateway once the model is deployed to Azure. The endpoint is accessible (without the gateway) from management studio and fromvisual studio.

Right.  So the Fabric SQL endpoint will also be accessible directly from Azure Analysis Services after you deploy the model.

No, you get this message: 'On-Premise Gateway is required to access the data source. Please install a unified gateway for the server [servername] or disable AlwaysUseGateway setting if it's enabled. (setting is disabled)
I also dubbel checked this in another tennant, after being deployed to the analysis services server in Azure the connection asks for the gateway

Are you using the Azure SQL Database connector?

Yes, and I also tried using the Azure Synapase Analytics SQL connector.

Yep.  Looks like AAS examines the hostname to determine if a gateway is required.  I'm checking for updates.  But as a workaround you can use the ODBC Driver for SQL which supports ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal auth, where you can provision an App Registration and use the ClientID and ClientSecret as the username and password to connect.  You'll need to install the ODBC driver and set up the DSN on both your dev box and the gateway.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/odbc/download-odbc-driver-for-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver16

Do you maybe have some tips on getting the connection string right:
Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};description=FabricODBC;server=[fabrichash].datawarehouse.fabric.microsoft.com;uid=[sphash];Pwd=[pwdhash];app=Tabular Editor;wsid=vmweboomodgdphu;database=warehouse;encrypt=Optional;trustservercertificate=Yes;authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal
It works on the vm but not when it is deployed to the AAS server

Do you have the ODBC driver installed on the server?

Yes, and the connection string works with Tabular Editor. It does not work after being deployed to AAS. Tabular Editor is installed on the same server as the gateway server. I tried changing the connection string here en there but nothing seems to work. The connection string is created by the GUI. And ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server seems to be installed correctly.

How about just using a DSN name in the connection string?

It also did not work, it consumes to much time for now so unfortunately we decided not to continue with Fabric for this project, for now. Thank you very much for your help!

I've spent too much time trying to write a PowerShell script to update data source settings before processing, and it's been a nightmare. From what I understand, there is currently no way to have unattended access for Azure Analysis to pull data from a SQL endpoint. You must use a Microsoft Account, which has a token expiry of one day, making it impossible to automate daily processing. If I'm mistaken, I'd appreciate clarification, as we've been looking into this for weeks. I understand the reasoning behind it, but not being able to use a Service Principal or Managed Identity in the .bim is very limiting.
